# Use contents of a cell to name cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array of cell arrays in Matlab, and I want to simplify things by naming each cell array based on the contents of one of it's cells.  Here is an example:

```
myCell1 = {'';'name1'; 'stuff';'two';'three'};
myCell2={'';'name2';'more stuff';'4';'things'};
Cell={myCell1, myCell2}
```

If I have `Cell` in the example above, I want to create two **unnested** cell arrays named based on the second row in each of them.  In this example, the result would be as follows:

```
name1 = 

''
'name1'
'stuff'
'two'
'three'

name2 = 

''
'name2'
'more stuff'
'4'
'things'
```

How can I do this?  I tried indexing as follows, but it doesn't work (I don't how to make MATLAB recognize that I want the string in the cell array to be a name).

```
Cell{1,1}{2}=Cell{1,1};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) to do this for you.  Basically, you create a command you would like executed in MATLAB as a string, then use `eval` to execute this command for you.  As such, you can do something like this:

```
for idx = 1 : numel(Cell)
    cel = Cell{idx}; %// Extract i'th cell
    name = cel{2}; %// Get the name
    %// Create a cell array of this name in your workspace
    st = [name ' = cel;'];
    eval(st);
end
```

What the above code is doing is that it accesses each nested cell in your overall cell array, extracts the name of the cell, uses `eval` to take that name of the cell, make that a variable and assign this to the nested cell that you extracted.

---

By executing this code, I get:

```
name1 = 

''
'name1'
'stuff'
'two'
'three'


name2 = 

''
'name2'
'more stuff'
'4'
'things'
```